# How to pass record id from aura application to lightning web component in Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components

aura:application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasSObjectName" access="global">
    <c:World></c:World>
</aura:application>
```

aura:component

```
<aura:component  implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride,force:hasSObjectName" access="global">
    <c:LWC  recordId="{!v.recordId}"></c:LWC>
</aura:component>
```

LWC

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    api,
    track,
    wire
} from 'lwc';

import {
    NavigationMixin
} from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class WesLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    backtoOppRecPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: {recordId},
                objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
    }
}
```

`< c:LWC >` Is lightning web component 
So I want to pass record id from lwc to aura application how can I do this

Comment: Can you post the code for your LWC? The way you are passing it from the application is correct. Did you get any error?

Comment: I have added you can see now

Comment: So when i click on backtoOppRecPage() button which in my template it doing nothing when click from application

Comment: ok and how are you passing that record id to your aura app?

Comment: that is i want to know

Comment: you can pass it directly from the app url for eg: https://mydomain11-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/TestApp.app?recordId=0030K00001LW1hMQAT, where TestApp is my app and recordId is the parameter.

Comment: i cannot see what you written

Comment: please check in the answer section. If you still have any doubts you can see my detailed blog post on this [here](https://sftrailmixer.blogspot.com/2019/08/how-to-pass-record-id-or-any-other-url.html)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283327/i-want-to-pass-the-record-id-in-my-lightningapplication-how-i-can-do-this

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the parameter in the lightning application and pass it using the app URL. This is how you can define it.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasSObjectName" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>    
    <c:LWC recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</aura:application>
```

This is how you pass it, say your application name is `TestApp` and you are passing `0030K00001LW1hMQAT` to `recordId`.

https://mydomain11-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/TestApp.app?recordId=0030K00001LW1hMQAT

Comment: This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
 [PromiseRejection: [object Object]]

Comment: it is showing this error

Comment: Here to pass direct LWC to aura application

Comment: like this we can do or we have to pass LWC first into Lightning Component then in aura application

Comment: you can pass directly to Lwc from Aura application